# Average monthly count over a date range

Tags: sql-server, date

Consider the following table.  Start_Date is when the fruit was received into inventory, and End_Date is when they were disposed of.  Note that these date ranges can overlap.  For instance, there were 20 apples in inventory from 2014-01-016 through 2014-02-01.

```
+------------------------------------------+
|           [HISTORY_TABLE]                |
+------------+------------+----------+-----+
| Start_Date | End_Date   | Type     | QTY |
+------------+------------+----------+-----+
| 2013-12-16 | 2014-02-01 | Apple    | 12  |
| 2014-01-16 | 2014-06-01 | Apple    |  8  |
| 2014-01-16 | 2014-04-11 | Banana   |  5  |
| 2014-03-16 | 2014-04-16 | Banana   |  7  |
| 2014-02-16 | 2014-03-01 | Orange   | 24  |
| 2013-02-24 | 2014-05-01 | Orange   |  2  |
+------------+------------+----------+-----+
```

What I'm interested in is the average monthly count for each fruit type.  For Apples in January, the total cumulative daily apples would be:

```
((12 apples * 15 days) + (20 apples * 16 days) = 
(180 apple days + 320 apple days) = 500 apple days
```

Since January has 31 days, the average is:

```
500 / 31 = 16.13
```

Thus, the average available Apples in January is 16.13.

There may be fruit types with identical dates, type, and quantity, but it is assumed that each record is a unique count of fruit.  The end result I'm looking for will look similar to below (except with all of the fruit.)  The numbers in the results are accurate (at least I think they are... I calculated them by hand):

```
+-----------------------------------------+
|  [RESULTS]                              |
+-------+------+------------+-----+-------+
| Month | Year | Fruit Type | QTY |  Avg  |
+-------+------+------------+-----+-------+
|  12   | 2013 | Apple      | 192 |  6.19 |
|  01   | 2014 | Apple      | 500 | 16.13 |
|  02   | 2014 | Apple      | 236 |  8.43 |
|  03   | 2014 | Apple      | 248 |  8.00 |
|  04   | 2014 | Apple      | 240 |  8.00 |
|  05   | 2014 | Apple      | 248 |  8.00 |
|  06   | 2014 | Apple      |   8 |  0.27 |
+-------+------+------------+-----+-------+
```

Some code to set up the initial data:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#LocalTempFruitTable', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #LocalTempFruitTable

CREATE TABLE #LocalTempFruitTable(
    Start_Date date,
    End_Date date,
    Type varchar(50),
    QTY int)

INSERT INTO #LocalTempFruitTable (Start_Date,End_Date,Type,QTY) VALUES ('2013-12-16','2014-02-01','Apple','12')
INSERT INTO #LocalTempFruitTable (Start_Date,End_Date,Type,QTY) VALUES ('2014-01-16','2014-06-01','Apple','8')
INSERT INTO #LocalTempFruitTable (Start_Date,End_Date,Type,QTY) VALUES ('2014-01-16','2014-04-11','Banana','5')
INSERT INTO #LocalTempFruitTable (Start_Date,End_Date,Type,QTY) VALUES ('2014-03-16','2014-04-16','Banana','7')
INSERT INTO #LocalTempFruitTable (Start_Date,End_Date,Type,QTY) VALUES ('2014-02-16','2014-03-01','Orange','24')
INSERT INTO #LocalTempFruitTable (Start_Date,End_Date,Type,QTY) VALUES ('2013-02-24','2014-05-01','Orange','2')

SELECT * FROM #LocalTempFruitTable
```

Comment: Definitely not "homework"... The real life report that I'm trying to build is significantly more complicated than this.  Using CTE, I've tried starting with a table of every day in a date range I'm looking at, then joining it with a list of every "fruit type" that was active during that day.  I'm using DATEPART to break up the dates into months and years, and attempting to group by that.  I'm getting results (which I can't share), but the numbers don't match up at all with what they should be.

Comment: LEFT OUTER JOIN dch_results ON 
 (dch_results.Start_Date <= daySpan.Date
  AND
   (dch_results.END_DATE >= daySpan.Date
    OR
    dch_results.End_Date IS NULL)
  )

Comment: Whaddaya know... I answered my own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are working with dates, you can exploit the fact that there aren't really that many of them.  It's perfectly feasible to track them individually. Create and populate a date table that covers the whole range you need, e.g:

```
CREATE TABLE date_list ([date] date PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL);

INSERT date_list([date])  
SELECT TOP 1000  --This is a quick-and-dirty example
  DATEADD(day,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL))-1,'2013-01-01')
FROM master.dbo.spt_values;
```

Then use this to assist the main query:

```
WITH daily_tally AS (
  SELECT
    [date],
    [Type],
    SUM(Qty) AS [daily_Qty]
  FROM date_list
  INNER JOIN Results ON [date] BETWEEN [Start_Date] AND [End_Date]
  GROUP BY [date],[Type]
)
SELECT
  MONTH([date]) AS [month],
  YEAR([date]) AS [year],
  [Type],
  AVG([daily_Qty]) AS [avg_Qty]
FROM daily_tally
GROUP BY MONTH([date]),YEAR([date]),[Type]
```

Comment: I ended up with the same conclusion as you did, but I'll give you the credit for working it out.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up with...  We have already created a function that returns every day between two date ranges:

```
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[udf_SpanOfDates]    Script Date: 06/09/2014 16:35:52 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_SpanOfDates]
(
    @StartDate Datetime,
    @EndDate DateTime
)

RETURNS
    @Dates TABLE
(
    Date DateTime
    , Month_MM integer
    , Quarter_QQ integer
    , Year_CCYY integer
)
AS
BEGIN
While @StartDate <= @EndDate
    begin
        insert @Dates 
        (   Date
            , Month_MM
            , Quarter_QQ
            , Year_CCYY
        ) 
        Values 
        (   @StartDate
            , DATEPART(M,@StartDate)
            , DATEPART(Q,@StartDate)
            , DATEPART(YYYY,@StartDate)
        )
        Set @StartDate = @StartDate + 1
    end

RETURN

END
GO
```

With that function, I was able to do this:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#LocalTempFruitTable', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #LocalTempFruitTable

CREATE TABLE #LocalTempFruitTable(
    Start_Date date,
    End_Date date,
    Type varchar(50),
    QTY int)

INSERT INTO #LocalTempFruitTable (Start_Date,End_Date,Type,QTY) VALUES ('2013-12-16','2014-02-01','Apple','12')
INSERT INTO #LocalTempFruitTable (Start_Date,End_Date,Type,QTY) VALUES ('2014-01-16','2014-06-01','Apple','8')
INSERT INTO #LocalTempFruitTable (Start_Date,End_Date,Type,QTY) VALUES ('2014-01-16','2014-04-11','Banana','5')
INSERT INTO #LocalTempFruitTable (Start_Date,End_Date,Type,QTY) VALUES ('2014-03-16','2014-04-16','Banana','7')
INSERT INTO #LocalTempFruitTable (Start_Date,End_Date,Type,QTY) VALUES ('2014-02-16','2014-03-01','Orange','24')
INSERT INTO #LocalTempFruitTable (Start_Date,End_Date,Type,QTY) VALUES ('2013-02-24','2014-05-01','Orange','2')

SELECT Month_MM,YEAR_CCYY,Type,SUM(QTY)
FROM    dbo.udf_SpanOfDates('2013-12-01', '2014-04-01') sD
INNER JOIN #LocalTempFruitTable fruit
    ON (fruit.Start_Date <= sD.Date
            AND
            (fruit.END_DATE >= sD.Date
                OR fruit.End_Date IS NULL)
        )
GROUP BY MONTH_MM,YEAR_CCYY,Type
ORDER BY YEAR_CCYY,Month_MM,Type
```

Results:

```
MM  YEAR    Type    FruitDays
12  2013    Apple   192
12  2013    Orange  62
1   2014    Apple   500
1   2014    Banana  80
1   2014    Orange  62
2   2014    Apple   236
2   2014    Banana  140
2   2014    Orange  368
3   2014    Apple   248
3   2014    Banana  267
3   2014    Orange  86
4   2014    Apple   8
4   2014    Banana  12
4   2014    Orange  2
```

At this point, calculating the average is academic, since I already have the month and the "fruit  days".

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE
(
 Start_Date DATETIME,
 End_Date DATETIME,
 Type VARCHAR(20),
 Qty DECIMAL(19,6)
)

INSERT INTO @MyTable
( Start_Date, End_Date, Type, Qty )
VALUES
( '12/16/2013', '02/01/2014', 'Apple', 12),
( '01/16/2014', '06/01/2014', 'Apple', 8),
( '01/16/2014', '04/11/2014', 'Banana', 5),
( '03/16/2014', '04/16/2014', 'Banana', 7),
( '02/16/2014', '03/01/2014', 'Orange', 24),
( '02/24/2013', '05/01/2014', 'Orange', 2);

DECLARE @MinDate DATETIME
SELECT @MinDate = MIN(Start_Date) FROM @MyTable
DECLARE @MaxDate DATETIME
SELECT @MaxDate = MAX(End_Date) FROM @MyTable


DECLARE @number_of_numbers INT = 100000;

;WITH
a AS (SELECT 1 AS i UNION ALL SELECT 1),
b AS (SELECT 1 AS i FROM a AS x, a AS y),
c AS (SELECT 1 AS i FROM b AS x, b AS y),
d AS (SELECT 1 AS i FROM c AS x, c AS y),
e AS (SELECT 1 AS i FROM d AS x, d AS y),
f AS (SELECT 1 AS i FROM e AS x, e AS y),
numbers AS 
(
    SELECT TOP(@number_of_numbers)
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS number
    FROM f
)


SELECT d.Type, MONTH(d.CheckDate), YEAR(d.CheckDate), AVG(D.Qty) FROM
(
SELECT c.CheckDate, m.Type, SUM(m.Qty) Qty FROM
(
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, n.number, '1/1/2000') AS CheckDate FROM numbers n
) C
LEFT JOIN @MyTable m
    ON c.CheckDate >= m.Start_Date and c.CheckDate <= m.End_Date
WHERE c.CheckDate >= @MinDate AND c.CheckDate <= @MaxDate
GROUP BY c.CheckDate, m.Type
) AS d
GROUP BY d.Type, MONTH(d.CheckDate), YEAR(d.CheckDate)
```